# How to rename xml element of string[] in c#?

Tags: c#, xml

In c#, I do this

```
    public string[] SearchTags { get; set; }
```

and then when I serialize it to XML, it looks like

```
<SearchTags>
    <string>A</string>
    <string>B</string>
</SearchTags>
```

But I want it to look like

```
<SearchTags>
    <Tag>A</Tag>
    <Tag>B</Tag>
</SearchTags>
```

I tried this:

```
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Tag")]
    public string[] SearchTags { get; set; }
```

but it ends up removing the `SearchTags` wrapper, and just puts

```
    <Tag>A</Tag>
    <Tag>B</Tag>
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
[XmlArray("SearchTags")]
[XmlArrayItem("Tag")]
public string[] SearchTags { get; set; }
```